# conversion of epsilon NFA to NFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I was given below task:
*Eliminate Epsilon-transitions in below automata*

[image]

My solution:
[image]

Is it correct that stage 1 is actually one of the final stages?
How does it work in given example? We have nothing on the input and it's still going to be accepted? Is it because epsilon here is hidden? Am I understanding that right or did I make a mistake in the solution?

Kind regards,